# DCEF3 - version of Chromium

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm using Delphi Chromium Embedded DCEF3, revision 24038bd3a600, downloaded from https://dcef3.googlecode.com/archive/24038bd3a600df2feb349cd0cffd68a8da40bd12.zip

Which version of Chromium corresponds to this version of DCEF ?

Answer (score 3):

The `libcef.dll` contained in the ZIP file has version `3.1650.1562.0`.

According to [CEFBuilds](http://cefbuilds.com/), that corresponds to `Chromium 31.0.1650`.